# hibernate load selected column

Tags: hibernate

I have a table:
User with columns: { id, name, address}

I want to use hibernate to select only the id from this table. But i don't want to use HQL for native SQL query. I want to use the Criteria object. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Sean Nguyen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You have to use a Projection :

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class, "u");
c.setProjection(Projections.property("u.id"));
return c.list(); // the list of all the user IDs
```

But HQL is much more readable and straightforward for this kind of query. Criteria is useful for dynamically built queries, or to reuse parts of queries in several ones :

```
return session.createQuery("select u.id from User u").list();
```

Comment: Or rather use c.setProjection(Projections.id());

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply a ResultTransformer to native SQL queries, allowing it to return non-managed entities.

as an example, say we have entdemodetail entity like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "demodetail") 
public class EntDemodetail {

    Integer id;
    String description;
    Integer demoid;
    EntDemo demo;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_detail", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="detaildesc")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    @Column(name="demoid")
    public Integer getDemoid() {
        return demoid;
    }

    public void setDemoid(Integer demoid) {
        this.demoid = demoid;
    }


    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="demoid")
    public EntDemo getDemo() {
        return demo;
    }

    public void setDemo(EntDemo demo) {
        this.demo = demo;
    }

}
```

you can read some columns of this entity like below

```
/* Method to  READ some columns of an entity with native sql */
       public void nativesqlwithresulttransformer( ){
          Session session = HibernateUtilMysql.getSessionFactory().openSession();
          Transaction tx = null;
          try{
             tx = session.beginTransaction();

             String sql = "SELECT id_detail as id FROM demodetail d"; //
             SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

             List results = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EntDemodetail.class)).list();

             for (Iterator iterator = 
                               results.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                EntDemodetail entdemodetail = (EntDemodetail) iterator.next(); 
                System.out.print("Id: " + entdemodetail.getId()); 
                //System.out.print("Desc: " + entdemodetail.getDescription()); 

             }
             tx.commit();
          }catch (HibernateException e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             e.printStackTrace(); 
          }finally {
             session.close(); 
          }
       }
```

for more information , you can see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querysql.html